# New switch statment without return

Tags: c#

I have trouble with using new `8.0` `switch` statment. In my case i don't need to return anything from switch nevertheless all examples i found uses return. I would like to have something like this below (psudo code). Keep in mind for some cases i need to put multilines. Is something like this possible?

```
operationType switch
                {
                    OpType.Handle
                    { 
                        //do something
                        //do something
                    }
                    OpType.Move => //do Something
                    _ => throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(operationType), operationType, null)
                };
```

Comment: *"i don't need to return anything from switch"* - use a `switch` *block* for that.

Comment: They're not called "new `8.0` `switch` statment", they're called "[switch expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#switch-expressions)", and they're just that: expressions. It is syntactic sugar to make your code more readable, and just look at the code you posted. Is that more readable that a couple of `if()`s?

Comment: @CodeCaster so when i dont want to return anything should i just use normal switch statment? I thought i could rid off break for isntance..